# CakePHP Error: Class 'Auth' not found

Tags: cakephp

I am newer in `cakephp` and below my code

**App Controller**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array( 'Session','Auth');
    function beforeFilter()     {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }
}
```

**Admins Controller**

```
class AdminsController extends AppController {
  function admin_login()
  {
    echo(AuthComponent::password($this->data['Admin']['password']));
  }
}
```

When I submit username and password it shows **Error: Class 'Auth' not found**. Please help me what I missing?

Comment: As far as i remember the way to use a component is `$this->{componentName}`, You'll get the doc here : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Comment: @NeoPix I think `AuthComponent::password` is deprecated in `cakephp 2.6.1`.

Comment: Yes, you got to use a password hasher class now, more infos here : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords

Comment: `Class 'Auth'` ? There is no such class in the whole framework. You must have a typo somewhere - and didnt use `AuthComponent` as class name when accessing it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check and make sure that your AdminsController file has the following at the top:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
```

This needs to come BEFORE the class declaration.

In addition I highly recomend you use the debug() tool to echo out your code while debugging.
So,

```
echo(AuthComponent::password($this->data['Admin']['password']));
```

Would become:

```
debug(AuthComponent::password($this->data['Admin']['password']));
```